# Dialogflow CX no-input default action for parameters

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Anytime a user does not specify a response to a parameter prompt, I would like to trigger a WebHook.

My **Start** page has a `No-input default` event handler, but this only seems to apply to page-level prompts, not parameter-level.

Do I need to configure a set of `No-input` handlers for every parameter on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to apply no-match-* and no-input-* to each parameter too. These are reprompt event handlers are they are available for each parameter. You can either set the no-input-default or the no-input-1, no-input-2, etc.

Check out: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#event-parameter

Comment: So, no way to set it in a global way, I need to apply it to each parameter

Comment: You can add these event handlers at the specific page level also but keep in mind that it will be tedious to understand which parameter is to be filled, etc. It is more appropriate to do it at a parameter level, and then via no-input-1/2/3 -- you can guide the user to the specific information that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, yes but you can create a custom parameter to manage all of the `no-inputs` that you want to use on your start page, also it's better to use them on a parameter level.

To do so you can add a parameter with entity type @sys.any, which can capture the user input and put the value into the variable.

[image]

Then you’ll be able to use a route to check if the user_input meets the condition.

[image]

Comment: @SamBarnum Was my answer helpful for you?